# How to not allow users to create new tags, but allow to them to use existing ones

Tags: plugins, functions, tags

I want a certain role to be able to add new tags, but other users should just be able to use the text bar to search for existing tags.

I know I can hide the tag bar in the sidebar, but I don't want that. I just want it to say "Sorry, this tag does not exist" or something when someone enters a tag that doesn't exist.

Is there a plugin or a function that will do that for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can hook onto `pre_insert_term`, check the taxonomy and whether or not the user has the specified role as follows:

```
function disallow_insert_term($term, $taxonomy) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( $taxonomy === 'post_tag' && in_array('somerole', $user->roles) ) {

        return new WP_Error(
            'disallow_insert_term', 
            __('Your role does not have permission to add terms to this taxonomy')
        );

    }

    return $term;

}

add_filter('pre_insert_term', 'disallow_insert_term', 10, 2);
```

This will prevent the user inserting new terms but allow them to search and add existing terms to a post.

Beaware that when on the post edit screen a user can enter in a term name that does not exist and press enter or click the add button which will add the term to the DOM however at this point the term is not added to the database until the user publishes or updates the post at which point the term will be disallowed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help :) I have tried this, but it didn't seem to do anything. I'll be honest and say it's probably my own fault. I copy pasted your code in my functions and of course changed the 'somerole' bit. Adding tags is still possible for that role.

Comment: What is the user role you are trying to prevent? Also are you trying to prevent tags for the correct taxonomy, in this case `post_tag` and not some other taxonomy like `categories` or some custom taxonomy?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent the editor role from doing it at the moment. And it's the standard taxonomy (so that should be post_tag), I haven't created anything else yet as i'm still testing.

Comment: Time to start debugging then. In `wp-config.php` set the following constants, `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, 
`define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`, and 
`define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` then in the function snippet above, log a call to `error_log($taxonomy);` and another call to `error_log(implode(', ', $user->roles));` then add a tag then update the post, this will then create a `debug.log` file in the `wp-content` directory. You need to work out whether or not this function is being called and whether or not it is entering the conditional statement correctly because this callback works for me.

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/nX9ZLubH

Comment: Seems to work now. I checked the functions file again (because no debug file came up) and it seems I had a line of code that messed things up. So now it works. I don't get the Error message saying "Your role does not have permission to add terms to this taxonomy" though.

But thanks!

Comment: Great. In the case of `WP_Error`, you won't see that error message anywhere unless you work with the error object specifically. The reason why we throw a `WP_Error` in this instance is because `wp_insert_term()` in `wp-includes/taxonomy.php` checks for an error object using `wp_is_error()` and if true, it will return the `$term` passed to the function as opposed to inserting it into the database. I suggest you take a look at the aforementioned function in WP core to get an idea of whats happening. Here is a reference to `WP_Error` too: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error

Comment: Thank you. I've never used these things, so I've learned a lot :)

Comment: Before closing the function you must add a line to `return $term;`

Comment: @Pons good catch, `return` statement included. Also updated from `add_action` to `add_filter` to make it more obvious that this callback may be expecting a return value outside of conditional statements.

Comment: Really does prevent, but the new-created disallowed tag doesn't always disappear on the frontend, so it looks like allowed (until you start typing next one). Also I can see the error in the console, wonder where user should see it.